# Regular distribution on manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, distribution-theory

Let $M$ be a compact $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifold with volume form $dV$. By analogy with the Euclidean case, call a distribution $\mu$ on $M$ (that is, a continuous linear functional on $C^{\infty}(M)$) *regular* if there exists $f\in L^1(M)$ such that
\begin{align*}
\langle \mu,\varphi\rangle = \int_M \varphi(x)f(x)dV
\end{align*}
for all $\varphi\in C^{\infty}(M)$. Is it true that if there exists a constant $C$ such that
\begin{align*}
\lvert\langle \mu, \partial_i\varphi(x)\rangle\rvert \leq C\lvert\varphi\rvert_\infty
\end{align*}
for all $i=1,\dots,d$ and all $\varphi\in C^{\infty}(M)$, then $\mu$ is regular?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: I think it's true. It's certainly true in the Euclidean case. One proof I've seen in the Euclidean case involves convolution with a Gaussian and a few other steps I'm not sure translate to the Riemannian case. Another proof in the Euclidean case uses Sobolev embedding. I don't understand the argument well enough to determine what translates to the Riemannian one. My suspicion, primarily based on the validity of Sobolev embedding for compact Riemannian manifolds, is that everything from the Sobolev embedding argument translates just fine.

Comment: I can add either proof of the Euclidean case to my original post if that's useful.

Comment: Sobolev embedding should be fine, but the Euclidean argument (with different volume form) should work fine with a (finite) partition of unity argument should work.